# Does Elastic Beanstalk support Amazon's Aurora DB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-aurora

In the Oregon region, Elastic Beanstalk let's me select "aurora" from a list of RDS databases. However, when I try to launch the application, I get this flash message:

`DBEngine: Invalid option value: 'aurora' (Namespace: 'aws:rds:dbinstance', OptionName: 'DBEngine'): Value is not one of the allowed values: [mysql, oracle-se1, postgres, sqlserver-ex, sqlserver-web, sqlserver-se]`

Is this a transient error, or is Aurora not available on Elastic Beanstalk? Why would they let me select it if it wasn't a real option?

Answer (score 5):

As of 2015-08-07, Elastic Beanstalk does not support Aurora. I received this message from AWS Support:

> Hello,
>   At this time it is not currently a supported option for use with Beanstalk, though we are working to expand where and how it can be integrated.  Please stay tuned to our release blog for any updates in the near future pertaining to that.
>   https://aws.amazon.com/new/

Sot it's not available today, but it's likely coming soon.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: Still not available 5 years later.

Answer (score 2):

As per the previous answer, you may not be able to create an Aurora database as part of an Elastic Beanstalk environment, however, you are still able to create each independently and allow access from the Elastic Beanstalk security group to the database instance by editing the inbound rules for the RDS instance's incoming permissions. Also, when you deploy your code to Elastic Beanstalk, you would need to include a MySql library that would enable you to connect to the Aurora instance. I'm not going to specify what those libraries are as each language can vary. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is doable but requires a bit of configuration. From Amazon's own Beanstalk documentation:

> If you need a high-performance database, consider using Amazon Aurora. Amazon Aurora is a MySQL-compatible database engine that offers commercial database features at low cost. To connect your application to a different database, repeat the security group configuration steps and update the RDS-related environment properties.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-ha-tutorial.html (second last paragraph at the bottom of page)